# How to avoid full table scan

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database around 50GB size with millions of rows. Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mac` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`firstTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`lastTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`locid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`isOut` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_logs_on_location_id` (`location_id`),
KEY `index_logs_on_client_id` (`client_id`),
KEY `macID` (`macID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39537721 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I was looking ways to avoid full table scans. I tried to add index for mac column. However when I run `EXPLAIN` on my queries, possible_keys and keys are always NULL when I don't use `client_id` in `WHERE` clause, otherwise my only used index is client_id or location_id which doesn't have a significant effect on my queries in the sense of execution time. I mainly use these types of queries(grouping,sorting etc..)

```
SELECT mac,COUNT(mac),DATE(lastTime)
FROM logs
WHERE client_id = 1
GROUP BY mac,DATE(lastTime)
```

When you consider this type of table structure, how can I optimize my table to execute queries faster? I'm open to all suggestions. Thank you

Comment: have an index on `client_id`?

Comment: I think you might need to have an index on all 3 columns - `mac, lastTime, client_id`. It's either that or just have one for `client_id` as @TZHX suggested.

Comment: @TZHX Yes, I have index on both client and locid however i didn't set index for lastTime which is a Datetime column.

Answer (score 1):

To get MySQL (or Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MariaDB, DB2 and others) to use an index depends on how unique is the data in the *mac* column and how the distribution of the uniqueness is. The database engines mentioned use a cost based optimizer which estimates the cost of a certain solution and execute the solution with the lowest cost. Sometimes they are incorrect. This estimate can be influenced by playing with database parameters, however this can have unexpected side effects on other queries.

The second way to influence the result is to change the data structure.

The third way, most feasible is to influence the execution plan by providing a hint. For this lets assume an index is present on `mac` and `lastTime` so that the db engine only needs to load this index to do its job:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mac_nn_1 ON logs(mac,lastTime);
```

The assumed to be optimized query is (so your version without the `client_id` column)

```
SELECT mac,COUNT(mac),DATE(lastTime)
FROM logs FORCE INDEX idx_mac_nn_1
GROUP BY mac,DATE(lastTime);
```

This then should force MySQL to use the index no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to try two column indexing but lastTime is a Datetime column. Is it meaningful to index it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I understood the index concept however some queries are fast and some of them not. I got 220k unique mac values, but 3 client_id only (one of the clients got 190k unique mac values). Each mac value might appear more than once and I always run custom queries, not predefined. Maybe I should change my table structure? What do you think?

Comment: For instance this query took 5mins after creating an index with mac and client_id columns.
 `SELECT d, COUNT(mac)
FROM
(SELECT macID, COUNT(DISTINCT(lastTime)) AS d
FROM logs
WHERE client_id = 121 AND isOut = 0
GROUP BY mac) l
GROUP BY d `

Comment: I just notice 1 point in this query: Remove the `DATE` function, or introduce an extra column in the correct format so you do not need to apply the `DATE` function: That will give the optimizer a better chance of picking the right index.

Comment: 5 minutes for such a set of highly unique values (`mac`) is not bad. Is it better than the original full table scan (just wondering)? Is the load CPU bound or IO bound? If it is IO bound maybe look into compression and partitioning the table and see if you can gain some performance that way. If it is CPU bound, getting rid of the DATE function might help you.

Comment: Ok I will check it and I'm going to add an extra column for date. I think it might work

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT mac, COUNT(mac), DATE(lastTime)
FROM logs
WHERE client_id = 1
GROUP BY mac, DATE(lastTime)
```

You want an index on `(client_id, mac, lastTime)`.  I would suggest a covering index, if you don't mind the extra space required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I asked to Norbert but I'm asking again, is it useful to index a datetime column which is lastTime?

Comment: Your question is very general.  It depends on the query, so there are cases where it might be useful.  Neither answer suggests an index only on `lastTime`.

Comment: Yes you are right, there are different indexing methods maybe for different queries. I'm just trying and see the effects.